# how to know google map could not calculate directions from place a to place b in android

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, direction

i want to show **direction from place A to place B**, by using **google map application** and **intent**

1. at first i find **latitude** and **longitude** of both places
2. then i use below URL to show the direction between 2 places

   "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat1 + "," + lng1 + "&daddr=" + lat2 + "," + lng2

it;s OK and all things goes right **but** s.times google map **can't** find direction and it shows below error

> Sorry, we could not calculate directions from place A to place B

i read about this error and understood that

> the directions is not supported in every country of the world

but , **here is my question** that how can i get this error to show users, my own sentence instead of opening google map application with intent and then google map shows this to users

**UPDATE :** here is the URL , u can test it
[it will show "Sorry, we could not calculate directions"](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/33.5132762,51.9130553/30.3548893,56.002705/@31.9237095,51.7145804,7z/data=!3m1!4b1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Google Maps rest api. [More about it here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)
You can use [status codes from the response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#StatusCodes)

Answer (score 0):

as @karandeepsingh answered and as **Document** said

> The following request returns driving directions from Toronto, Ontario
>   to Montreal, Quebec.
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY

it returns a JSON by sending 2 city name, and finally we will check **status**

- **"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"** if google map **could not** calculate directions from place A to place B
- **"status" : "OK"** if google map **found** directions from place A to place
  B